# Including Award Values on Academic CV When Applying For Graduate School

Tags: phd, application, cv, awards

I am going to be applying to schools for a PhD in the not so distant future and I received a couple of scholarships in my masters degree that are worth over $10 000.00. I am not sure if it would be a wise idea to include the values next to the awards or just the actual award names themselves. Here are a couple of thoughts I have as to why I should and shouldn't:

**Should**

- Including the award values could be a good signal for graduate committees that I am somebody who is proactive in seeking self funding.
- Including the award values might suggest that I have potential to attract more money of the same magnitude

**Should Not**

- It could be considered unprofessional to add award values - I have no idea
- It could be potentially viewed as arrogant, boisterous, and off putting
- Graduate committees don't actually care how much they're worth and can look the awards up if they're interested.

Question: Should a prospective PhD student include award/scholarship values on the academic CV? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that if I were reading the CV that I'd care one way or the other. If the award has a name or title, you should list that: Award/grant from IBM to support research in "glub-bending at the cusp". But adding the amount is also fine. My response to seeing the amount would be "interesting", but not "yay" or "nay".

But the important thing, to me would be the fact of the award, not its amount. Not a big deal, though. Others might have different opinions, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to include award values for research grants, including training fellowships, in a CV. Done with tact, I would see this as a positive and unlikely to be taken as arrogant.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure if I'd include scholarships in the same category, but I don't think it would hurt.